# Finding total cost of Dijkstra path

Tags: python, networkx

I have the shortest path between two nodes in a network.

I am trying to find the total cost between the two nodes.

```
import numpy as np 
import networkx as nx

def shortest_path(a,b):
    m = np.array([[0,2,1,....]])
    network = nx.from_numpy_matrix(m)
    path = nx.dijkstra_path(network, source=a, target=b)
    ix =[[path[i],path[i+1]] for i in range(len(path)-1)]
    total = sum([m[i[0]][i[1]] for i in ix])
    path = nx.dijkstra_path(network, source=a, target=b)
    return(total, path)
```

I was just wondering if there is an attribute to find the total cost variable instead of me having to code it up so that my code looks cleaner? I can't seem to find it in the docs as I am very new to networkx. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`single_source_dijkstra`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.single_source_dijkstra). Example usage for you (adapted from example in documentation):

```
total, path = nx.single_source_dijkstra(network, source=a, target=b)
```